# Date range for MYSQL BETWEEN statement

Tags: mysql, between

Suppose I have a date range in query `from 2013-02-01 to 2013-02-10` and I want to compare it with date ranges from subset of the date excluding the edge dates eg. `date range 2013-02-02 to 2013-02-09`. Do I have any chance of using `BETWEEN` statement in query whiech can exclude edge dates?
Actually what I wanted to with this is, incase there are several date ranges between the given dates i want to exclude them

Comment: Not understanding your question. Can you just add `23:59:59` or is it just a `date` field?

Comment: @njk  `date <= '2013-02-10 23:59:59'` not the same as `date< '2013-02-11 0:00:00'`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I'm implying using `BETWEEN`.

Comment: @njk Yes of course. I'm too.

Comment: Do you want to compare two ranges or date with range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) and DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)` you can exclude edges.
Then with 2 between statements you can check the intersection on the begin date and the end date.

Comment: Hi Yoh!! Its working as required!! this is the query...  THANKS!!             (from AND to NOT BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2013-01-29', INTERVAL 1 DAY) and DATE_SUB('2013-02-04', INTERVAL 1 DAY))

Answer (score 0):

yohannc is Right;
 For example to deduct one day from last date you can use

`BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND DATE_SUB('2013-02-10' , INTERVAL 1 DAY)`